# Create an Order Calculation Page using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web

This script is supposed to allow the user to calculate their total bill for all items they would like to order.

When the user selects an item and quantity, the products and related fields should be added to the next available row in the list. Also, the Unit Price and Price field should be automatically calculated and filled in.

My question is, where do I start? I'm confused on which method to use for JavaScript.

Here is my code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>The Irish Homeland Micro-Brewery</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function calcList() // *** call "Add to List" button to function ***
{
    var BeverageItem = document.getElementById("beverageSelection").value;
    var QuantitySelection = document.getElementById("quantitySelection").value;

}

</script>
</head>

<body align="center">
<h1>Irish HomeLand Micro-Brewrey Cost Calculator</h1>
<p>Order Some Beverage(s) below</p>
<p>
    Beverage: 
    <select id="beverageSelection">
        <option value="24.99" id="shama">Shamrock Ale - $24.99/case</option>
        <option value="27.99" id="lucky">Lucky Pillsner - $27.99/case</option>
        <option value="27.99" id="irishw">Irish Wheat - $27.99/case</option>
        <option value="32.99" id="irishm">Irish Malt - $32.99/case</option>
        <option value="35.99" id="shamr">Shamrock Rye - $35.99/case</option>
    </select> 
Quantity:
    <select id="quantitySelection">
        <option value="1" id="opt1">1</option>
        <option value="2" id="opt2">2</option>
        <option value="3" id="opt3">3</option>
        <option value="4" id="opt4">4</option>
    </select>
    <!--- use the button to add together ---> 
    <input type="button" value="Add to List" id="addList" onClick="calcList()">
    <input type="reset" id="resetBtn" value="Clear All">
</p>
<table align="center" border="1" style="width:50%">
    <tr >
        <td>Item Description</td>
        <td>Unit Price</td>
        <td>Qty</td>
        <td>Price <sup>(unit*qty+ship)</sup></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="txtItem1" readonly></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txtUnit1" readonly></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txtQty1" readonly></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txtPrice1" readonly></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="txtItem2" readonly></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txtUnit2" readonly></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txtQty2" readonly></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txtPrice2" readonly></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="txtItem3" readonly></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txtUnit3" readonly></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txtQty3" readonly></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txtPrice3" readonly></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="txtItem4" readonly></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txtUnit4" readonly></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txtQty4" readonly></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txtPrice4" readonly></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="txtItem5" readonly></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txtUnit5" readonly></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txtQty5" readonly></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txtPrice5" readonly></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="txtItem6" readonly></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txtUnit6" readonly></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txtQty6" readonly></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txtPrice6" readonly></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td align="right">Total</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="total" readonly></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Would it be possible to trim this code sample down a bit, so that only the part needed to reproduce the problem is there?

Comment: @APerson i can't bcoz I do not understand the question.

Comment: @APerson Did you never seen this: "What is your programming question? Be specific" and see examples here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  i think you need it!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61296/discussion-between-aperson-and-krupal-shah).

Comment: ah, sorry. new here. let me see if i can make sense of this question

Answer (score 1):

The core of your problem is that you can't access values from select boxes like you do text inputs.   You need to find the `selectedIndex` to get it's value.

So, change

```
document.getElementById("beverageSelection").value;
```

to

```
var fld = document.getElementById("beverageSelection");
var fldval = fld.options[fld.selectedIndex].value;
```

then you can do your math in the calc function to get your totals from the `fldval` variable